# How to make a prod build in "Ionic upload" command?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to use Ionic deploy service in Ionic cloud.

When I run `ionic upload` command, a dev build is immediately triggered instead of prod build.

Is it possible to create a `--prod` build and upload?

One of major reasons is that multiple configurations in my code are bundled with `--prod` build only.

```
ionic upload --deploy=dev
[INFO] Running app-scripts build:

[09:55:59]  build dev started ...
[09:55:59]  clean started ...
[09:55:59]  clean finished in 1 ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pipe the npm scripts to run the ionic `--prod` first and then ionic upload

```
"scripts":{
   "custom-upload":"ionic cordova build --prod | ionic upload"
}
```

and then run in the terminal

```
$: npm custom-upload
```

This will still run the dev build i think but your prod build should be packaged as well. It does not look like you can specify a build type in the ionic upload command, which makes me think that the ionic upload does not upload the production build to ionic view. And if that is that case then you might want to consider changing the configurations setup in a prod build to be set to only be used if not on localhost instead on based on the build.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is good. I eventually found that `ionic upload` accepts `--prod` and `--nobuild` parameters..